# Keeping a log of user changes in web application

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, struts-1

What is the best way to keep a log of user changes in my web application (java/tomcat/struts/mysql)?  I give out accounts and each account has multiple users.  I want the account administrators to be able to see who did what at any given time. And I'd like to be able to access ALL of it.  First, I need a way to know which fields have been changed, then I need to log the changes for each account in a place where they can see them.  Obviously, I don't want to slow the app down.  I read an answer on this site suggesting keeping a db log - querying the database for changes after each query is sent.  Wasn't sure how to do that.

Answer (score 3):

This depends on the nature of your web application. Let's assume your web application is a e-commerce system and it allows the user to add new product, or updating an existing product. When a user perform a specific action like adding a new product, the basic goal is to capture his user name, action and time stamp. Same for updating a product, you might want to keep track what values he updated, what was the old value and when did he change that.

To achieve this, firstly you need to

1. Create an audit table

   - Obviously you want to keep track the last modified person, timestamp, created by and etc.
2. Create a logging mechanism whenever some changes/actions performed.

   - There are few ways to do this, you can either do it via application or leave everything to database trigger. I would suggest to use triggers to detect any Create/Update/Delete event in the database, and ask the trigger to capture the details and write to the Audit table. I think this is the cleanest and less maintenance way. However, if you want to log using application, you have to make code changes, create new methods to capture the details to the Audit table in your action classes.

More information on MYSQL Trigger [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html)

Answer (score -1):

I was looking on a similar "Method" to log the transactions and other stuffs in my web app. Just while browsing Google, i found this link:
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Logging_Cheat_Sheet telling about two possible ways to log: Either on database or on filesystem at some log files...

> When using the file system, it is preferable to use a separate
>   partition than those used by the operating system, other application
>   files and user generated content For file-based logs, apply strict
>   permissions concerning which users can access the directories, and the
>   permissions of files within the directories In web applications, the
>   logs should not be exposed in web-accessible locations, and if done
>   so, should have restricted access and be configured with a plain text
>   MIME type (not HTML) When using a database, it is preferable to
>   utilize a separate database account that is only used for writing log
>   data and which has very restrictive database , table, function and
>   command permissions Use standard formats over secure protocols to
>   record and send event data, or log files, to other systems e.g. Common
>   Log File System (CLFS), Common Event Format (CEF) over syslog,
>   possibly Common Event Expression (CEE) in future; standard formats
>   facilitate integration with centralised logging services

They've beautifully explained the possible ways we can log, what should be logged, what to be avoided too.

Hope it's useful to you.